# is workerpool compatible with python3.4 on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed workerpool using pip install and the installation worked fine.

```
import workerpool
```

I get

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\workerpool\__init__.py in <module>()
     23 for performing a specialized type of job.
     24 """
---> 25 from exceptions import *
     26 from jobs import *
     27 from pools import *

ImportError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

I had no problem with other modules yet.

**Is workerpool coompatible with python3.4?** 
Do you see a solution to the problem above?

**Update 1**

after applying the suggestion of cpburnz below:

I bubbed into this error

```
      C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\workerpool\pools.py in <module>()
----> 8 from Queue import Queue
      9 if not hasattr(Queue, 'task_done'):
     10 # Graft Python 2.5's Queue functionality onto Python 2.4's implementation

ImportError: No module named 'Queue'
```

What would be the next step?

Comment: I'm working on Windows. Yes I pip install. The exception module is in the same directory as workerpool and the __init__.py seems fine as well.

Comment: This also happens on Ubuntu for Python 3.3, but not Python 2.7.

Comment: The `Queue` module was renamed to `queue` in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source for [workerpool/__init__.py](https://github.com/shazow/workerpool/blob/master/workerpool/__init__.py#L27), it appears that [workerpool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/workerpool) is not compatible with Python 3 because of the [implicit relative imports](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). E.g.,

```
from exceptions import *
from jobs import *
from pools import *
from workers import *
```

Now, if you wanted to fix this problem you could edit the source to:

```
from .exceptions import *
from .jobs import *
from .pools import *
from .workers import *
```

And glancing through the rest of the source files it looks like it might work if all of the implicit relative imports were fixed.

---

In Python 3, the [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) module was renamed to [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). To fix that you can change:

```
from Queue import Queue
```

To:

```
from queue import Queue
```

Or, if you want to support both:

```
try:
    from queue import Queue
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue
```

That import occurs in:

- [workerpool/QueueWrapper.py](https://github.com/shazow/workerpool/blob/master/workerpool/QueueWrapper.py#L10) on line 10.
- [workerpool/pools.py](https://github.com/shazow/workerpool/blob/master/workerpool/pools.py#L8) on line 8.

Comment: nice try!. It lead me to another Import Error. Do you think repeating the same procedure would be a solution? I posted the next error. above

Comment: Thanks for going through these changes. Another solution is to run the 2to3 tool for code translation. We really should build it into the setup.py (anyone interested in making a PR?).