# Python3, Urllib3: Fast server friendly requests to single site in the order of 100,000 requests?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I am trying to get a subset of the entire Old Bailey Online archive via the web API.

My problem is that my implementation is not just slow, but the server stops servicing my request fairly promptly (about 10 minutes).

Currently I am using the dev version of urllib3 as:

```
import urllib3
retry = urllib3.util.Retry(total=1000, read=200, connect=200, backoff_factor=0.5)
timeout = urllib3.util.Timeout(connect=2.0, read=4.0)
http=urllib3.PoolManager(retry=retry, timeout=timeout, maxsize=10)
```

Then I run all my requests with this http pool. The numbers I chose are fairly ridiculous, but the best yet 8(

For every year, I need to make 70 concurrent requests, over 243 years and for differing scenarios.
 I tried using workerpool by @shazow (modified to work with python3.4 as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046895/398969 ), concurrently within year, multithread years, which did not work too well either. Mostly due to server timeouts and my ignorance.

Is there appreciable delay introduced by DNS lookup? I cannot use an Ip as the domain is a apache virtual host (or can I?)

Soo. the real question: How can I download hundreds of thousands of times from the same server 'nicely' and in a timely way? I still expect it to take a day or so 8)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the server might be throttling/banning your IP for making too many requests too frequently.

First, I'd suggest checking the robots.txt on the domain to see if there is any guidance on automated request frequency. If not, you could ask the owner of the website to advise on how to best crawl the site. Otherwise, you may need to determine the rate limiting experimentally.

To throttle your requests, you can use something like [apiclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apiclient).RateLimiter* ([source](https://github.com/shazow/apiclient/blob/master/apiclient/ratelimiter.py)). It would look something like this:

```
from apiclient import RateLimiter
from urllib3 import PoolManager

lock = RateLimiter(max_messages=30, every_seconds=60)
http = PoolManager(...)
...

for url in crawl_list:
    lock.acquire()
    r = http.request(...)
```

Another thing you could do is crawl a cached version of the site, if one is available through Google or archive.org.

[*] *Disclaimer: I also wrote apiclient a long time ago. It's not super-well documented. I suspect there are other similar modules that you can use if you find it lacking, but the source should be reasonably easy to understand and extend.*

Comment: No robots.txt, nor on the parent site. Will have a better go at getting apiclient to work with python3.4 mostly is urllib -> urllib.parse stuff. should be easy... Only mild success changing numbers around.